# Erro de função não definida ao trabalhar com ECMAScript modules no browser

Tags: javascript, html, módulo-ecmascript

Estou tentando trabalhar com módulos no JavaScript e me deparei com um problema ao chamar uma função que está no arquivo `main.js` pelo `index.html`.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>ES modules</title>
    <script type="module" src="./main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <script>
        fnFuncionou()
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Esse `main.js` importa uma variável de texto de outro arquivo, o `mods.js`.

```
import texto from './mod.js'
console.log(`Fora da função ${texto}`)

function fnFuncionou() {
    console.log(`Dentro da função ${texto}`)
}
```

Abaixo o código do `mods.js`:

```
let texto = "funcionou!"

export default texto
```

Ao executar o `index.html`, recebo a mensagem do `console.log(`Fora da função ${texto}`)`, que está fora da função no `main.js`. Porém, a função `fnFuncionou()` não é chamada, dando a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> ```
> index.html:10 Uncaught ReferenceError: fnFuncionou is not defined
> ```

Alguém saberia me dizer o porquê disso acontecer? É possível chamar esta função `fnFuncionou()` sem alterar a estrutura de arquivos da pasta? Eu resumi o problema, pois os arquivos que estou trabalhando tem bem mais códigos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você adiciona o atributo `type="module"` em um script, ele não é mais tratado do modo convencional. Por isso, as funções (globalmente) nele declaradas não ficam acessíveis ao HTML.

Por isso que você não pode chamar `fnFuncionou` no seu HTML, assumindo que ela faz parte do escopo global. Não é isso que acontece.

Ao trabalhar com módulos, você deve ser explícito. Portanto, você deve importar `fnFuncionou`. Assim:

<sub>Arquivo `main.js`:</sub>

```js
import texto from './mod.js';

console.log(`Fora da função ${texto}`);

// Note que a função está sendo exportada:
export default function fnFuncionou() {
  console.log(`Dentro da função ${texto}`);
}
```

<sub>Arquivo `index.html`:</sub>

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>ES modules</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="module">
    import fnFuncionou from './main.js';

    fnFuncionou();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note que utilizei o atributo `type="module"` no `<script>` de `index.html`. Caso contrário, não poderia utilizar o `import` *statement*.

A saída será algo como:

```
Fora da função funcionou!
Dentro da função funcionou!
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!